# Access server running on ubuntu host from guest in virtualbox

Tags: node.js, network-programming, virtualbox

I have a nodejs project running in ubuntu. so I access it this way:

http://localhost:9000/login

now I am trying to access this server from a guest windows7 which I am running on virtual box.

My ubuntu IP is 192.168.1.13 and my VM network configuration is Bridged Adapter so I am trying

http://192.168.1.13:9000/login

But it does not work

However, when I run in the cmd 'ping 192.168.1.13' It replies successfully.

Could someone tell me what else I have to do to access my server from the guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to achieve, your Node.js application should listen on the specified IP address and port which is accessible from other systems.

You just can't expect the user from outside world(OS) to access your web-application which is running in your system's localhost.

Change your code to something like this for allowing it to listen on `APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS`(substitute your IP, which is 192.168.1.13 in this case) :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  // your code 
}).listen(8080, 'APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS');
console.log('Server running at http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/');
```

Also, for further accessibility, check [How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Answer (score 1):

Look at file /etc/hosts and check how localhost is mapped. Surely it is set to 127.0.0.1 . If you make your nodejs application listen on IP:port 192.168.1.13:9000 you will be able to connect. Or change the mapping of localhost which I don't recommend.